# Installing Zombie.js Error: ReferenceError: Set is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, installation, mocha.js, chai, zombie.js

**Background:** I'm currently reading "*Web Development with Node and Express*" by Ethan Brown (great book by the way for those learning node and express) and I got stuck on Chapter 5 - Quality Insurance.

Everything was running smooth. First I ran the following:

> npm install --save-dev mocha
>
> npm install -g mocha
>
> npm install --save-dev chai
>
> npm install --save-dev zombie

**Problem:** Then I ran (as the book instructed):

> mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tests-crosspage.js 2>/dev/null

But this wasn't doing anything. So then I ran:

> mocha -u tdd -R spec qa/tests-crosspage.js

And then this error appeared:

> /Users/esanz91/Desktop/CodingNotes/Node/MySite/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:405
>   var nonInheritedTags = new Set([
>
> ReferenceError: Set is not defined

**Versions:**
Just to give you guys an idea, I have the following versions installed.

> **cmd:**
>
> npm list --depth=0
>
> **results:**
>
> ├── chai@2.2.0
>
> ├── express@4.12.3
>
> ├── express3-handlebars@0.5.2
>
> ├── mocha@2.2.4
>
> └── zombie@4.0.7

Also, I'm running on Node 0.10.

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) is a new type introduced by ECMAScript 6. Running mocha with V8's `--harmony` flag should make it available.

Comment: I couldn't figure why Set wasn't being recognized. Now it makes sense. Thanks @JonathanLonowski.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question. I actually needed to downgrade Zombie 4.0.7 to 3.1.x so that the mocha test command could work with Node 0.10.

Edit1: I decided to upgrade my Node version to 0.12 and my Zombie version back up to 4.0.7 and that worked too. (seems like Node 0.10 and Zombie 4.0.7 not compatible...)

Edit2: For anyone reading the book, I suggest looking at the github [repo](https://github.com/EthanRBrown/web-development-with-node-and-express) by the author himself. Take a look at the package.json file to see which version of the modules he uses.

Comment: Saved me some time. Thanks