# Changing Version of Zombie.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, zombie.js

I need to change my install of zombie.js from 4.0.7 to 3.1.x as specified here ([Installing Zombie.js Error: ReferenceError: Set is not defined. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662551/installing-zombie-js-error-referenceerror-set-is-not-defined-what-am-i-doing)) to work through an example.

However I have no idea how to do this using the linux command line (nor did my search yield an answer to this). Is there a way to do this using npm?

Answer (score 1):

```
 npm install zombie@3.1.0 --save
```

Comment: Thanks, was missing the @