# nodejs cannot find module 'zombie' with PHP mink

Tags: php, node.js, mink, zombie.js

I'm trying out [Mink (PHP)](https://github.com/minkphp/docs/blob/master/index.rst) on Ubuntu 14.04; I basically did the following:

```
$ apt-show-versions nodejs
nodejs:amd64/trusty 0.10.45-1nodesource1~trusty1 uptodate
$ npm -v
2.15.1
$ sudo npm install -g zombie
npm WARN engine zombie@4.2.1: wanted: {"node":"^4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.45","npm":"2.15.1"})
...
zombie@4.2.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/zombie
├── ms@0.7.1
├── debug@2.2.0
...

$ ls /usr/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/
babel-runtime  bluebird  debug  eventsource  iconv-lite  jsdom  lodash  mime  ms  request  tough-cookie  ws
```

So, basically, even if I get a warning, the modules build, and should be in the directory `/usr/lib/node_modules`.

Then I do:

```
mkdir test_php_mink
cd test_php_mink/
composer require behat/mink
composer require behat/mink-zombie-driver
```

As a check:

```
test_php_mink$ ls
composer.json  composer.lock  vendor
```

... it seems all `composer` files are there.

Finally, as per http://mink.behat.org/en/latest/drivers/zombie.html (and also [Cannot find module 'zombie' · Issue #84 · assaf/zombie · GitHub](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/issues/84)), I'm trying this script:

```
<?php

# composer autoload:
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

echo "safe_mode: '" . ini_get("safe_mode") ."'\n"; # have PHP 5.5.9, safe_mode is removed

putenv("NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules");
echo "NODE_PATH is: '" . getenv ( "NODE_PATH" ) . "'\n"; # OK, is there

# NOPE:
#$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver();

$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver(
  new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer()
);

$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start the session
$session->start();
?>
```

This script, unfortunately, still fails with:

```
$ php test_php_mink.php 
safe_mode: ''
NODE_PATH is: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Server process has been terminated: (8) [
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'zombie'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/test_php_mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/bin/mink-zombie-server.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
]' in /path/to/test_php_mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php:413
Stack trace:
#0 /path/to/test_php_mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php(306): Behat\Mink\Driv in /path/to/test_php_mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php on line 413
```

How can I get this basic example to run?

---

EDIT: Played around a bit more with this, and discovered that when I specify the environment variable on the command line:

```
$ NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules php test_php_mink.php
safe_mode: ''
NODE_PATH is: '/usr/lib/node_modules'
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Server process has been terminated: (8) [
/usr/lib/node_modules/zombie/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/level2/html.js:238
var nonInheritedTags = new Set([
                           ^
ReferenceError: Set is not defined
...
```

... then the module seems to be found! So my question basically reduces to: how can I change the `NODE_PATH` environment variable from my php script, so I wouldn't have to specify it on the shell - since apparently `putenv("NODE_PATH=/usr/lib/node_modules");` does not really work for me...

As for the new error, there is [Installing Zombie.js Error: ReferenceError: Set is not defined. What am I doing wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662551/installing-zombie-js-error-referenceerror-set-is-not-defined-what-am-i-doing) - apparently this is due to the version mismatch that I got a warning for (`npm WARN engine zombie@4.2.1: wanted: {"node":"^4.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.45","npm":"2.15.1"})`), so I guess I'll have to install `nvm` so I can install the right nodejs version; and I also noticed in `/usr/lib/node_modules/zombie/README.md`:

> **Zombie 4.x** is tested to work with [io.js 1.6 or later](https://iojs.org/en/index.html).
>   If you need to use Node 0.12 or earlier, consider using Zombie 2.x. ...
>   To install Zombie.js you will need [io.js](https://iojs.org/):
>   ```bash
>   $ npm install zombie --save-dev
>   ```

... and I think that can also be installed with `nvm`; so I'll give that a try...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found some sort of a method which seemingly works - but I'd still like someone more knowledgeable to answer.

Anyways, the trick is - `zombie` can accept a path to the `nodejs` binary; so if you cannot really pass environment variables for `nodejs` from PHP, then make a shell script which will set these environment variables, and then call `nodejs`.

First this was my install:

```bash
# remove previous
sudo npm uninstall -g zombie --save-dev
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs && sudo apt-get autoremove --purge

# install new
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
nvm install iojs-v3.3.1
npm list -g --depth=0
nvm install 4.0.0
npm list -g --depth=0
npm -g install zombie --save-dev
```

The problem with `nvm` is that it installs in a user directory, and I'd like to test my scripts both on my user machine and remote server, where my uids are completely different. Regardless, using a custom executable helps a bit with that. So, create a script in a "global" location, I chose `/home`, so I'll need `sudo` to create files there:

```
sudo touch /home/node_pth.sh
```

... then paste in the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NODE_PATH=/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules
#echo ARGS ARE "$@" | tee -a /tmp/node.log
/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/bin/node "$@"
```

... of course, replacing the paths with your correct ones; then finally make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/node_pth.sh
```

Now we can use the following `test_php_mink.php` PHP file:

```php
<?php

$nodeModPath = "/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules"; # correct NODE_PATH, but will not help
$nodePath = "/home/node_pth.sh"; # shell script that sets NODE_PATH, then calls node executable

echo "NODE_PATH is: '" . getenv ( "NODE_PATH" ) . "'\n"; #
putenv("NODE_PATH=".$nodeModPath);
echo "NODE_PATH is: '" . getenv ( "NODE_PATH" ) . "'\n"; # is there - but still doesn't help with call

# composer autoload:
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

echo "safe_mode: '" . ini_get("safe_mode") ."'\n"; # have PHP 5.5.9, safe_mode is removed


$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver(
  //~ new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer()
  # copy defaults here for everything but nodeBin;
  # see vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php
  new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer("127.0.0.1", 8124, $nodePath, null)
);

$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start the session
$session->start();
?>
```

---

... OR, I just realized there is `setNodeModulesPath($nodeModulesPath)` in `vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php`, so we can drop the proxy bash executable altogether:

```
<?php

$nodeModPath = "/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules"; # correct NODE_PATH, but will not help via putenv

echo "NODE_PATH is: '" . getenv ( "NODE_PATH" ) . "'\n"; #
putenv("NODE_PATH=".$nodeModPath);
echo "NODE_PATH is: '" . getenv ( "NODE_PATH" ) . "'\n"; # is there - but still doesn't help with call

# composer autoload:
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

echo "safe_mode: '" . ini_get("safe_mode") ."'\n"; # have PHP 5.5.9, safe_mode is removed

$zsrv = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer();
$zsrv->setNodeModulesPath($nodeModPath . "/"); # needs to end with a trailing '/'

$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver( $zsrv );

$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

// start the session
$session->start();

?>
```

Anyways, when this script is called, it outputs:

```
$ php test_php_mink.php
NODE_PATH is: ''
NODE_PATH is: '/home/USERNAME/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules'
safe_mode: ''
```

... and as there are no errors, I'm assuming it is all fine now...